# How to boot live distribution with secure boot enabled?

Tags: grub2, kernel, uefi, live-usb, secure-boot

I want to try the live distribution, but I have on my laptop secure boot enabled and I can't disable it because of locked BIOS (company notebook, I can't do anything about it). Is there any way to start the live distribution with secure boot enabled? Please don't tell me to sign the kernel, it's live distribution and I don't want to tweak the iso. I really need to try the official image, not any customized one (I have another problem where I want to compare official distribution and my installation). Is there any kernel parameter I could use to boot the kernel from live iso?
Thanks

Comment: What is the "distribution"? Ubuntu will boot with Secure Boot. Other distros are off-topic.

Comment: Standard Ubuntu desktop, Ubuntu Server and the official Ubuntu community flavours (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu) work with secure boot.

Comment: Which burning tool are you using to turn the ISO into a boot media?  Some tools may manipulate things to the point (They burn only legacy, use grubx64.efi instead of shimx64.efi, etc.) that the produced media will not work with secure boot enabled.

Comment: Insert your Ubuntu boot media; and boot your Secure-uEFI device and the system will boot.  If the ISO is written correctly to thumb-drive; the system will boot; as all Ubuntu releases are tested & boot in BIOS, uEFI & Secure-uEFI devices.. I'm involved in QA-testing & that's a ticked off item!   If the ISO is re-ordered & written in a *unsupported* way that is the fault of the user as the *supported* method works.

Comment: If it's a "Company notebook" you may be in violation of the company's policy by installing Ubuntu. You can get fired for violating company policy.